# Drop-down list using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

I have drop-down with some value,if i change those value based on that will display another dropdown with value from mysql database by replacing the text below first drop-down.I am doing this process in jsp page.Second drop-down values are come from database when changeevent of first dropdown.My database contain two tables,one for country and other for city.country table contain the fields countryid and country_name and the city table contain the fields cityid,countryid and city_name.Below is my code that i did so far.Here i need to implement ajax and jquery ? Could you give me the code for fetchCites servlet code for populating the second drop down without using any php or .net pages.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>  
function createRequestObject(){  
var req;  
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
//For Firefox, Safari, Opera  
req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
}  
else if(window.ActiveXObject){  
//For IE 5+  
req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  
else{  
//Error for an old browser  
alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');  
}  
return req;  
}  

//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object  
var http = createRequestObject();  
function sendRequest(method, url){  
if(method == 'get' || method == 'GET'){  
http.open(method,url);  
http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;  
http.send(null);  
}  
}  

function handleResponse(){  
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){  
var response = http.responseText;  
if(response){  
document.getElementById("second_dropdown_code").innerHTML = response;  
}  
}       
}  

function getCityDropdown()  
   {  
   var w = document.myform.mylist.selectedIndex;  
   var country_id = document.myform.mylist.options[w].value;  
    sendRequest('GET','fetchCites.do?countryid=' + country_id);  
   }  

</script>  
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <FORM NAME="myform">  
<SELECT NAME="country" onChange="getCityDropdown()">  
<OPTION VALUE="1">India</option>  
<OPTION VALUE="2">England</option>  
</SELECT>  
</FORM>  
<div id="second_dropdown_code">This text will be replaced by second City dropdown.     
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this thing in your coding

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
<option>Select Country</option>
<option value="223">USA</option>
<option value="224">Canada</option>
<option value="225">England</option>
<option value="226">Ireland</option>
</select>

<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="state">
<option>Select Country First</option>
</select>
```

Ajax Code

```
$(function() {
$('#country').change( function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == 223 || val == 224) {
        $('#othstate').val('').hide();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'findState.php',
           dataType: 'html',
           data: { country : val },
           success: function(data) {
               $('#state').html( data );
           }
        });
    }
    else {
       $('#state').val('').hide();
       $('#othstate').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry,i can't use any php or .net pages here

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to populate the given state dropdown

```
   <SELECT NAME="sate" id="sate">  

    </SELECT>
```

Your json must be

```
[{
    "state": "MP"
},
{
    "sate": "UP"
}]
```

And use the following code to populate the drop down of state. It makes the ajax call and get the response as the ajax object which is an ajax array and iterate through the array.

```
  function getStateDropdown() {
    var w = document.myform.mylist.selectedIndex;
    var country_id = document.myform.mylist.options[w].value;

    $.ajax({
        url : 'fetchState.do?countryid=' + country_id,
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                $("#state").append(
                        "<option value=" + i + ">" + val.state+ "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```